# How to disable logging for rails 4 caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How can I disable logging for caching in "rails 4.1"? Specifically I'm trying to get rid of fragment caching log entries like these:

```
Write fragment views/... (0.3ms)
Read fragment views/... (0.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
# config/initializers/log_subscriber.rb
module ActionController
  class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
    %w(write_fragment read_fragment exist_fragment?
       expire_fragment expire_page write_page).each do |method|
      class_eval <<-METHOD, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{method}(event)
          return
        end
      METHOD
    end
  end
end
```

Test locally with:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

(With the usual caveat to test carefully in your own app. This "works," but is the hammer method, and can trap you or other, unwary programmers later.)

Comment: Thanks, far from ideal but I guess there is no alternative better than this.