# How to disable logs for fragment caching in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have a application in which continuously the log is being written by:

```
Read fragment views/locations/946-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/947-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/948-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/949-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/950-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/951-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/952-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/953-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/954-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/955-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/956-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/957-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/958-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/959-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/960-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/961-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/962-20150420170206 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/963-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/964-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/965-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/966-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/967-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/968-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/969-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/970-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/971-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/locations/972-20150420170207 (0.1ms)
```

which is filling the log and making the file in some GB size. So I want to disable the logs for the cache read and write so I can stop this. I have tried various things:

```
module ActionView
  class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
    def logger
      @memoized_logger ||= Logger.new('/dev/null')
    end
  end
end
```

I kept this file in initializers folder but didn't help. The second thing in initializer I tried is:

```
Rails.cache.silence!
```

But still nothing changed. Also I tried this in `production.rb`:

```
config.cache_store.silence!
```

But this threw an error. I think probably there is no `cache_store` defined.

Also in the initializers I tried this:

```
# Create logger that ignores messages containing “CACHE”
class CacheFreeLogger < ::Logger
  def debug(message, *args, &block)
    super unless message.include? 'Read fragment'
  end
end

# Overwrite ActiveRecord’s logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  CacheFreeLogger.new(STDOUT)) unless Rails.env.test?
```

Still no help.

I got another answer which might help but I don't know how to use this. Here is the link:

[How to disable logging for rails 4 caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203068/how-to-disable-logging-for-rails-4-caching)

Can someone please help me disabling the logs for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might substitute the default `Rails` log [formatter](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#attribute-i-formatter):

```
@logdevice = Rails.logger
                  .instance_variable_get(:@logger)
                  .instance_variable_get(:@log) # get rails logger

@formatter = @logdevice.formatter # store formatter value
@logdevice.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, message|
   @formatter.call(severity, datetime, progname, message) \
     unless message =~ /#{STOP_WORDS_REGEXP}/ # call unless there is a stop word
end
```

This code might be put anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mudasobwa but can you please elaborate the answer a bit so I can understand it. And also how can I call it or where should I keep this code?

Comment: Updated. You are not supposed to call this code, once run, it will substitute the default `Rails` formatter for you, filtering out all the crap. The crap is to be specified as `STOP_WORDS_REGEXP`.